# how to set threshold for retrieving images in dataset by trail and error method?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have calculated the feature vectors  for all images that are present in dataset. I have used euclidean distance for calculating distance between them and retrieving top 10 similar images from the dataset with every query. Setting 
'Threshold' value is totally new to me please suggest some examples for selecting it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible answers of different degrees of difficulty:

Simple: return the 10 images with smallest distances.  If the query image is not very similar to anything in the data set, the returned images won't be very similar, but they would be the most similar anyway.  No threshold needed.

More complex: get a few people to rate pairs of images as being similar or non-similar (either yes/no or 0-10 scale).  You can figure out from that what euclidean distance most people would say is "not similar" (or would give a score below 5, etc).  That is your empirical threshold (but: it may be different for different kinds of images - I still think you will find a typical distance that works pretty well in most cases).

Even more complex: cluster your images with kNN.  Try this for many possible numbers of clusters; measure the average cluster size, eg as median(distance(feature vector, centroid of cluster) for each image in cluster).  Similarly measure the distances between pairs of clusters.  This gives you an idea of what is "close" and "not close": but again ideally you should use for each image the size of the cluster it is in.

Comment: Suppose I have features vectors of 18 images of one cluster are :                                  749, 495, 614, 761, 582, 640, 555, 870, 663, 746, 627, 746, 644, 416, 614, 554, 764, 487.                                                                                                      if I choose 640(mean) as threshold value only half of images will be retrieved in every cluster with every retrieval.                                                                           but threshold value should sometimes shows more images as output and sometimes less no of images as output.